# send commands i2c raspberry to EZO ph sensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, i2c

I'm trying to send command to this sensor, when I sent a single byte command everything works good, commands like "i", "R". But when I try to send commando as words "sleep" or "STATUS" I can't.

```python
from smbus import SMBus
import time
import array as arr

bus = SMBus(1)
address = 0x63
sleep = "sleep"
data_receive = ""
data = b'wikito'
data5 = ""
print(data)
print(type(data))

output = data.decode()
print(output)
print(type(output))
# Commands
device_information = 0x69 #i
device_information_string = "i"

def ConvertStringsToBytes(src):
    converted = []
    for b in src:
        converted.append(ord(b))
    return converted

def ConvertBytesToString(src):
    print("hola")

data2 = ConvertStringsToBytes(device_information_string)
print(len(data2))
data3 = data2[0]
print(data3)
print(data2)
x = bus.read_byte(address)
print(x)
bus.write_byte(address, data3)
time.sleep(1.5)
data_receive = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, 1, 12)
print(data_receive)
string = ''.join(map(chr, data_receive))
print(string)
time.sleep(2)
print("bloque")
data4 = ConvertStringsToBytes(sleep)
print(data4)
bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, 0x01, data4)
time.sleep(1.5)
```

I want to know how to send word commands as in this picture:

[image: Sending commands to device]